# Laravel Test: Add attribute to pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to write a test case in Laravel. I have found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#model-factories) how to create dummy data for a many to many relation between two models. But I could not find how to add attributes to the pivot table.

**Here an example:**
We have a model `user` and a model `car`. Each user can drive multiple cars, each car can be driven by multiple users and we want to capture how much miles each user drove with each car.

`users` table

```
 id | name
  1 | Bob
  2 | Alice
```

`cars` table

```
 id | name
  1 | Red Car
  2 | Blue Car
```

`car2user` relation table

```
 id_user | id_car | miles
  1      | 1      |  20
  2      | 2      |   4
```

How can I create such a test case? I tried

```
$user = factory(\App\User::class)->create(['name' => 'Bob'])->first();

$user->cars()->save(factory(\App\Car::class)->create(['name' => 'Red Car']));
```

But this raises the error:

> General error: 1364 Field 'miles' doesn't have a default value

I accept this error message, because I did not specify anywhere the value for the mandatory field `miles`. But where can I provide that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass extra pivot attributes as second argument to **save()** method. The following should do the trick:

```
$user->cars()->save(factory(\App\Car::class)->create(['name' => 'Red Car']), ['miles' => 20]);
```

Comment: Oh now I understand! The save method is the same that I use for my Eloquent queries, because I call it on the relation `cars()`! I thought the save method is something special with PHPUnit and this whole call was a black box for me.. THe only difference is that I call the Eloquent method with a fake model. This is so nice!  Thank you!